# Correct way to show an output from for loop in a label

Tags: wpf, vb.net

hi I have a code that can transform the lower case letters of each element of a String array using for loop. the problem is only the last element is appearing on the output(label) but shows fine on the debug output

```
    Dim lst() = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}

    For Each item As String In lst
        Dim array() As Char = item.ToCharArray
        array(0) = Char.ToUpper(array(0))

        Dim newS = New String(array)
        Dim value As String = String.Join("/", newS)
        TextBox1.Text = value
        Debug.Write(value)

        Output.Text = value
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("")
```

this is the problem that occurs, it changes the label into an into the last element with the uppercase letter as it it is meant to be, but
i want the output to be the same as the debug output which is

AppleBananaCherry

Comment: And what do you expect to happen here? I can't see any label changed by that code.

Comment: i have changed the code, it seems i have posted the incomplete code, can you check it please?

Comment: i just need thee value inside the for loop to be accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly define a `Char` array. A String has a `Char(index)` property which is the `Default` property. We can use this directly on the String. `MyString(index)`

We assign the new `String` that is returned by the `Replace` method to an element of the array. `index` starts at `0`, the default value of an Integer, and is incremented on each iteration of the `For Each` loop.

Finally, after the `For Each`, we assign the `Join` to the label.

Your code and where it went wrong.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim lst() = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}

    For Each item As String In lst
        Dim array() As Char = item.ToCharArray
        array(0) = Char.ToUpper(array(0))

        Dim newS = New String(array)
        Dim value As String = String.Join("/", newS)
        TextBox1.Text = value 'Overwrites the last value you assigned to the Text property
        Debug.Write(value) 'Adds on to the last value it wrote in the debug window.

        Label1.Text = value 'Overwrites the last value you assigned to the Text property
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("")
End Sub
```

Corrected code.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim lst = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
    Dim index As Integer
    For Each item As String In lst
        lst(index) = item.Replace(item(0), Char.ToUpper(item(0)))
        index += 1
    Next
    Label1.Text = String.Join("", lst)
End Sub
```

This is WinForms but the code you care about shouldn't be any different, just the Event procedure format.

Comment: i get a bit confused when using the for loop , and thankyou i should be reading more about this

Answer (score 0):

You can even make it in a single line without an explicit loop.

```
Dim lst = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
Output.Text = String.Join("", lst.Select(Function(x) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(x))))
```

While it seems very "smart" there are a couple of things to consider.

- If the original list is very big (meaning thousands of strings) this
  is less efficient because the Linq Select and the subsequent Join
  will create a new list doubling the memory used.
- If you want to change more than the first character, the ToTitleCase
  method cannot work

Comment: then i would need to consider using this if only for small strings?

Comment: It depends from your definition of small. Probably with lists containing hundreds of strings there will be no substantial difference, with more strings some kind of bechmark using the StopWatch class should be done.